# Getting NETSDK1004 error while running .NET 5 ASP.NET MVC Web App

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, .net-5

I just installed .NET 5.0 SDK. It was installed completely. Then I create a project (ASP.NET Core WEB APP). But, I can not build the project now. Getting the following error. I searched everywhere but could not come to a conclusion. [image]

Comment: Did you run the dotnet restore command?

Comment: dotnet restore was not running. Then I uninstall one telerik package which I installed previously. Then dotnet restore worked fine. Which solved the problem as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dotnet restore` solved the issue.